# stateprovider in angularjs - not rendering the ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Alright. I am stuck with this part for two days. I have tried everything i know. 
I have my ui-router loaded and stateprovider defined. I have the UI as shown in several examples in website. But when i run, it is not showing my ui-view.

Index.html

```
<body  ng-app='ngBRep'>
<div>
    <div data-ng-include="'app/layout/shell.html'"></div>
</div>
<!--Angular-->
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</body>
```

Shell.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="shell as vm">
    SHELL
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Entry.html

```
<section id="entry-view" data-ng-controller="entry as vm">
    ENTRY
</section>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ngBRep', [
        'ui.router' 
]);
```

routes.js

```
var app = angular.module('ngBRep');

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', routeConfigurator]);

function routeConfigurator($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    $stateProvider
      .state('/', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'app/views/entry.html'
      })
        .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/profile.html'
        });
    // Send to login if the URL was not found

}
```

My expectation is when i browse to index.html, i should see 
SHELL
PROFILE

But i get only SHELL.

And the worst part, there is an existing website in our project that does exactly this and it works.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a script element for app.js and another for routes.js in your index.html?

Comment: where is profile.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6HADwYubdVcrMSdDnPhS?p=preview). The issue in this case is related to the fact, that we are using two features *(which are in fact not expected / not designed to be working together)*:

- `ng-include` - to populate the **root** view *(usually part of `index.html`)*
- `ui-router`  - to target the **root**, which is not loaded yet
- *and in fact that include is executed later than the `ui-router` default call to`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")`)*

So while this template is included into the root index.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="shell as vm">
    SHELL
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

We have to do this in its controller:

```
app.controller('shell', function($scope, $state, ....){
   $state.go("/");
});
```

This way we solve the difference in loading times *(router is ready sooner then included template, so missing the targets)*

Check that [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6HADwYubdVcrMSdDnPhS?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Radim. That worked. I checked the other code that i had which was working and it had the following in the app.js  app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$q', '$state',
        function ($route, $rootScope, $q, $state) {
        }]);

Comment: [cont] although nothing was inside the function, i guess the injection of $route, $routeScope did some trick.

Comment: Actually this has introduced new problem. When i try to browse /profile/series directly by giving the url in the browser, it always goes to '/' since i have $state.go("/"); in shell and shell loads first. Please help. Let me know if you want my new routes.js

Comment: found this link that supports my second comment. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4957