# Angular JS: include partial HTML inside another ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using an `index.html` created with Yeoman, that looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>

    <div ng-include="'views/main.html'"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I know that I cannot use an `ng-include` inside another `ng-include`, so I don't even try that, but **that's the objective that I want to achieve.**

I'm using `ui.router` in my **main.html** for the nested views, but I cannot do something like this:

```
<header class="header">
  <!-- Rather long HTML code that I would like to put in
       a separate file like 'views/parts/header.html' -->

</header>

<div ui-view="" class="container"></div>
```

---

One naive solution would be to eliminate the first `ng-include` and use it in the **main.html** for header, footer and stuff like that.

So, hit me with what you've got, but not with that!

---

**Edit:** this is what I would love to have (but can't, since I'm already inside an `ng-include`)

```
  <div ng-include="'views/parts/header.html'"></div>
  <div ui-view="" class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I do understand you properly, that all is possible. As described here:

- [stateprovider in angularjs - not rendering the ui-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334652/)
- and shown here in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6HADwYubdVcrMSdDnPhS?p=preview)

At the end, we can use both worlds, but we have to do one more thing:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state, ....){
   $state.go("/");
});
```

Because the `ng-include` and `ui-router` startup do not match together. We have to force state reload once the target *(i.e. the content of our `<div ng-include="'views/main.html'"></div>`)* is available.

*NOTE: expecting the content of main.html like this:*

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

That should solve the issue...

EXTEND: How to re-include?

*The `ui-router` power here seems to be unlimited.* We can *(re)*use the `ng-include` again, inside of the `ui-view`. So instead of this:

```
<div ng-include="'views/parts/header.html'"></div>
<div ui-view="" class="container"></div> // e.g. filled by content.html
```

We can move the header into the view itself `content.html`

```
<div>
  <div ng-include="'views/parts/header.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Observe that [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W1r0lyQdDHNofcLBGCRg?p=preview)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The routing is working fine, and the correct loading at startup of `ui.router` states is ensured by `app.run(function($state){});` in my `app.js`. I just want to add a partial HTML inside my **main.html**. Take a look at my update please.

Comment: In fact, once you are in the world of the `ui-router`, you do not be chained by the *`ng-include` limitation*. Simply, change your siblings `ng-include` and `ui-view` into two sibling views `<div ui-view="a"><div ui-view="b">`. Because exactly this way was `ui-router` designed. Please check: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views. Does this help? somehow...?

Comment: I am aware of the named views, but I think this is not the case. Named views would let me use several different views in a **single** state (and could also be reused). To add header and footer (for example) I would have to declare them in each and every state I'm using...

Comment: I extended my answer, and also created a plunker. As we can see, the `ng-include` could be part of the `ui-view`, injected by `ui-router`. Does that help? *(ui-router is awesome library;)*

Comment: @RadimKöhler is totally right. I think its the other way round, that domokun you misunderstood Radim's solution. To make things simpler, you can infect just have a parent state, display all your headers and footers, and then nest a child state that will be your content's container. It is much cleaner, and you dont even need ng-include anywhere else. Just my 2 cents worth.